# Suggesting orders off of grouped item demand

Tags: r

A team and I are working on a problem in which we are working on creating a report to suggest raw materials purchasing.

Let's say that we have a dataframe that looks as follows where each row is a week of data:

```r
demand<- c(0,0,0,1500,2100,0,1500,0,0,0,0)
supply<- rep(0, length(demand))

df<- data.frame(demand = demand, supply = supply)
```

What I would like to do in this case is group orders together in x number of weeks and then do the following:

Let's say x = 2 in this case. I would like to create groups in the data starting at a spot in which demand is greater than 0 in those two weeks. So in this case the groups would be 1500 and 2100, then also 1500 and 0. Then what I would like to do is place the sum of those two values in each group in the supply column in the index prior to the index at which each group starts.... so in group one starts at index 4, so I'd place 3600 in index 3. Group 2 starts in index 7 so I'd place 1500 in the supply qty at index six.

Additionally, If x = 4, there would be 1 group consisting of 1500, 2100, 0, 1500, and we would place 5100 in index 3 of the supply column.

Ideal output would be as follows for x = 2:

```r
demand<- c(0, 0, 0, 1500, 2100, 0, 1500, 0, 0, 0, 0)
supply<- c(0, 0, 3600, 0, 0, 1500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
df<- data.frame(demand = demand, supply = supply)
```

I have no idea how I would go about doing this but any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hard to understand, maybe post an ideal data frame?

Comment: Using the data you listed at the top of the question, could you show what output you want? It would help me wrap my head around exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your specifications are not fully explained.

But anyway, the code should be similar to

```r
library(tidyverse)


df1 <- data.frame(demand = c(0, 0, 0, 1500, 2100, 0, 1500, 0, 0, 0, 0))
for (x in 2:4) {
  df1 %>%
    mutate(
      cum_demand = cumsum(demand),
      zero_condition = demand > 0 |
        lead(cum_demand, default = FALSE, n = x - 1) > cum_demand
    ) %>%
    filter(zero_condition) %>%
    group_by(group = (row_number() - 1) %/% x) %>%
    summarise(cum_demand = sum(demand)) %>%
    print()
}
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   group cum_demand
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     0       1500
#> 2     1       2100
#> 3     2       1500
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   group cum_demand
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     0       1500
#> 2     1       3600
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   group cum_demand
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     0       1500
#> 2     1       3600
```